# Android: ListView with left status line

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

Need something like this: ListView and Status Line

[image]

Please could you suggest the best way to do this?
add for each row - line which be stretched over the whole height (and half for first and the last item), or a separate element?
Or maybe there already some library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, 3 different layouts would be the best choice, 1° element with the line stretching only in the second half, middle elements with full line stretch (both top and bottom) and the last element with only top line. You need to check the position in which you're inflating the layout, and inflate the correct one of your choice!

Answer (score 2):

Just make a View as a line.

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#45a"
        android:id="@+id/line"/>
```

and you can animate this view according